# Why does ls accept duplicate switches?

Tags: ls, options

I'm curious - is there a difference between `ls -l` and `ls -lllllllllllllllllllllllllllll`?

The output appears to be the same and I'm confused on why `ls` allows duplicate switches.  Is this a standard practice among most commands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Short answer**:

Because it's programmed to ignore multiple uses of a flag.

**Long answer:**

As you can see in the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;h=cd5996eb979f9e9319089e8c065b1276a1fbece8;hb=HEAD#l1645) of `ls`, there is a part with the function `getopt_long()` and a huge switch case:

```
1648       int c = getopt_long (argc, argv,
1649                            "abcdfghiklmnopqrstuvw:xABCDFGHI:LNQRST:UXZ1",
1650                            long_options, &oi);
      ....
1654       switch (c)
1655         {
      ....
1707         case 'l':
1708           format = long_format;
1709           break;
      ....
1964     }
```

The function `getopt_long()` reads all paramters given to the program. In case if `-l` the variable `format` is set. So when you type multiple `-lllllllll` that variable is set multiple times, but that does not change anything.

Well, it changes one thing. This huge switch case statement must run through multiple times, because of multiple `-l` flags. `ls` needs longer to complete with multiple `-l` flags. But this time is not worth mentioning. =)

Comment: Or to put it another way, rejecting them would be more work for the programmer than ignoring them.

Comment: +0.5 for saying what I was going to say, +0.5 for going to the source.

Comment: @Mark - Why is it more work for the programmer?

Comment: @Ryan, rejecting an extra "l" option requires tracking how many have been seen and printing an error message if there are too many.  Ignoring extra "l" options simply requires setting the format style to "long_format" any time an "l" is seen.

Comment: @Mark - I would thought it was be easier to perform a count of l and if it exceeds 1, print an error.

Comment: @Ryan, it's easier to not count at all.

Comment: @Mark - Does this apply to all flags or is it limited to a select few and is the same standard applicable to all commands?

Answer (score 21):

Because it's the right thing to do. Suppose you had a script doing something like:

```
ls $LS_OPTIONS -l "$dir"
```

where it's possible that `$LS_OPTIONS` already contains `-l`. It would be counter-intuitive and annoying for this command to produce an error and would require extra logic in the script to avoid it.

`-l` may not be the best example for this, but hopefully you can see how the concept applies in general. A much better example is compiler options in `$CFLAGS` that might duplicate explicit options in a particular invocation of the compiler.

Comment: The same thing could also happen if you had defined an alias which call `ls` with some set of options.

Comment: @kasperd: Yes. Although putting `-l` in your `ls` alias seems like a bad idea, the same issue is likely to arise with options that are nice in an interactive `ls` alias like `-p` or `--color=auto`.

Comment: The alias doesn't have to be called `ls`. `ll` might be an alias for `ls -l`, and on a system with that alias, I might type `ll -lart`.

Answer (score 11):

`ls` is not a `bash` command, but a separate executable that you happen to launch from `bash`. That said, `-l` is just a type of Boolean flag, which if present causes `ls` to use a long-style format for the output. Most programs will simply ignore multiple uses (`ls -ll` is the same as `ls -l -l`) of such flags, although there are some exceptions (as an example, if `-v` means 'verbose', then a program may interpret multiple uses to mean "be even more verbose").

Comment: An example of `-vvv` is `ssh`.

Comment: Or even `aptitude moo`

Answer (score 8):

Shell aliases would be pretty annoying if commands like `ls` did not allow repeated options.

Suppose you had

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Then, if conflicting flags were not allowed, it would be an error to issue commands like `ls --color=never` or `ls --color=auto` or `rm -i`.

Therefore, these commands are designed to let later flags override earlier ones.

Comment: *Conflicting* switches are sometimes disallowed. (Try rsync with both `--inplace` and `--delay-updates`, for example.) Some tools just take whatever comes last; `rm -if` is probably a good example there. But there is no conflict in ls's -l option, hence `ls -l` and `ls -ll` is not a problem, and it does not affect execution in any significant manner. Computers are good at mind-numbing repetition.